How to solve the web3modal vulnerability problem?
First installed npx create-next-app@latest, then npm install @web3modal/wagmi wagmi viem @tanstack. As a result, this error appears. What could be the ways to solve this?
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: react-native@0.74.1
npm WARN Found: react@18.3.1
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.11.4
npm WARN   node_modules/@emotion/react
npm WARN     @emotion/react@"^11.11.4" from @thirdweb-dev/react@4.6.14
npm WARN     node_modules/@thirdweb-dev/react
npm WARN     3 more (@emotion/styled, thirdweb, @emotion/styled)
npm WARN   63 more (@emotion/use-insertion-effect-with-fallbacks, ...)
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"18.2.0" from react-native@0.74.1
npm WARN node_modules/react-native
npm WARN   peerOptional react-native@"*" from @metamask/sdk@0.18.6
npm WARN   node_modules/@metamask/sdk
npm WARN   5 more (@metamask/sdk-install-modal-web, ...)
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"18.2.0" from react-native@0.74.1
npm WARN   node_modules/react-native
npm WARN     peerOptional react-native@"*" from @metamask/sdk@0.18.6
npm WARN     node_modules/@metamask/sdk
npm WARN     5 more (@metamask/sdk-install-modal-web, ...)
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: react-i18next@13.5.0
npm WARN Found: i18next@22.5.1
npm WARN node_modules/@metamask/sdk/node_modules/i18next
npm WARN   i18next@"22.5.1" from @metamask/sdk@0.18.6
npm WARN   node_modules/@metamask/sdk
npm WARN     @metamask/sdk@"0.18.6" from @wagmi/connectors@4.3.3
npm WARN     node_modules/@wagmi/connectors
npm WARN   1 more (@metamask/sdk-install-modal-web)
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer i18next@">= 23.2.3" from react-i18next@13.5.0
npm WARN node_modules/@metamask/sdk/node_modules/react-i18next
npm WARN   peer react-i18next@"^13.2.2" from @metamask/sdk-install-modal-web@0.18.5
npm WARN   node_modules/@metamask/sdk/node_modules/@metamask/sdk-install-modal-web
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: i18next@23.11.3
npm WARN node_modules/i18next
npm WARN   peer i18next@">= 23.2.3" from react-i18next@13.5.0
npm WARN   node_modules/@metamask/sdk/node_modules/react-i18next
npm WARN     peer react-i18next@"^13.2.2" from @metamask/sdk-install-modal-web@0.18.5
npm WARN     node_modules/@metamask/sdk/node_modules/@metamask/sdk-install-modal-web
183 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
9 moderate severity vulnerabilities
To address issues that do not require attention
  npm audit fix
To address all issues (including breaking chang
  npm audit fix --force
Run `npm audit` for details.

(npm audit fix --force) leads to an even worse situation

Try using yarn package manager to install, make sure you delete your lock file (if available) and the node_modules folder.
yarn install

